# Installing GraphicsMagick on RedHat Enterprise Linux

Tags: redhat

Is there a way to install GraphicsMagick without any X dependency being installed?
We are trying to use GraphicsMagick via nodejs like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/569824/how-to-properly-set-up-imagemagick-on-aws-server-using-nodejs-and-express) so we don't need X really.

These are the dependencies if we want to install the rpm:

```
    Installing:
GraphicsMagick                                  x86_64                                  1.3.17-1.el6                                        acc-epel6_x86_64                                          2.2 M
Installing for dependencies:
fontconfig                                      x86_64                                  2.8.0-3.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  186 k
freetype                                        x86_64                                  2.3.11-14.el6_3.1                                   acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  359 k
jasper-libs                                     x86_64                                  1.900.1-15.el6_1.1                                  acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  136 k
lcms-libs                                       x86_64                                  1.19-1.el6                                          acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  100 k
libICE                                          x86_64                                  1.0.6-1.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                   53 k
libSM                                           x86_64                                  1.2.1-2.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                   37 k
libX11                                          x86_64                                  1.5.0-4.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  585 k
libX11-common                                   noarch                                  1.5.0-4.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  192 k
libXau                                          x86_64                                  1.0.6-4.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                   24 k
libXext                                         x86_64                                  1.3.1-2.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                   35 k
libgomp                                         x86_64                                  4.4.7-3.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  118 k
libtool-ltdl                                    x86_64                                  2.2.6-15.5.el6                                      acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                   44 k
libwmf-lite                                     x86_64                                  0.2.8.4-22.el6                                      acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                   51 k
libxcb                                          x86_64                                  1.8.1-1.el6                                         acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  110 k
urw-fonts                                       noarch                                  2.4-10.el6                                          acc-rhel-x86_64-server-6                                  3.1 M
```

Comment: Generally dependencies are fairly self-explanatory - if they are listed as dependencies then you will need to install them as the package in question depends upon their presence. If I were you however, I'd be asking the developers of GraphicsMagick if there is any way around this (rather than asking here). In any case, why exactly do you wish to avoid installing any X components?

Comment: @BE77Y thx. I realize the question sounds weird. I'm asking because our ops team doesn't want any X dependencies installed as a policy but devs want to use GraphicsMagick headless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphicsMagick was compiled with X support, and links to some X libraries, so that its functions that require X will work. From the [README](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/README.html):

> GraphicsMagick requires an X server for the 'display', 'animate', and 'import' functions to work properly.

But note that dependency management does not install the X server itself. This means that it's generally not a real problem. You won't have X running just because you installed GraphicsMagick. This permits a scenario where the X server is *remote* (e.g. on the developer's workstation).

If this *still* bothers you for some reason, then you can always compile GraphicsMagick yourself, or tweak and rebuild its source RPM.